# A question on involutions on the Lie algebra of vector fields

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

**Edite** According to the essential comment of Ian Agol I revise the question as follows

For a smooth manifold $M$, is there a non identity  involution $\theta$ on the lie algebra   $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ such that $X$ is topological equivalent to $\theta (X)$, for all smooth vec. field $X$ on $M$?

This  question is  motivated by the fact that, on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ the linear vector field $\dot X=AX$ is  topological equivalent to the linear vector field $\dot X=-A^{tr}X$.

By topological equivalent, we mean existence of an orbit preserving homeomorphism.

Comment: What do you have in mind for the Killing form for the space of vector fields?

Comment: @IanAgol I apologize for my mistake in the question, I revised it. Thank you for your comment

Comment: On odd dimensional spheres, the antipodal map works.

Comment: @IanAgol your very essntial comment about the killing form is  a motivation to consider the following:The problem is that we do not have a "trace" for defining the killing form. From this obstraction, we extract the following construction. For  a  compact Riemannian manifold $M$, one can construct a sobolov hilbert space which contains $\chi^{\infty}(M)$ as a dense space(ex:$H^{\infty}$) such that for each smooth vector field $X$, the operator $ad(X)$ is  a bounded operator. Now we search for "trace class" operators, those $X$ for which $ad(X)$ is  a trace class operator.

Comment: @IanAgol This  gives us a Lie subalgebra of $\chi^{\infty}(M)$, consists vector fields for which $ad$ is  a trace class operator. Now a good question: To what extent this Lie algebra can be represented? What type of vector fields belong to this Lie  algebra? Obviously the Killing form can be defined on this Lie algebra.Can you help to modify this idea?

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: If $X$ is a smooth vector field then $\text{ad}_X$ math the Sobolev space of $H^k$-vector fields to the Sobolev space of $H^{k-1}$-vector fields. It is an unbounded operator on $H^{k-1}$ and its domain of definition consists of all $H^{k-1}$ vector fields which are $k$-times weakly differentiable along the flow lines of $X$. So there is no change to search for trace class operators among them.

Comment: @PeterMichor Thanks for your comment. What is the exact definition of $H^{\infty}$? Is It  a Hilbert space? I think such space soves the problem which you said

Comment: @Ali Taghavi: $H^\infty=\bigcap_k H^k$ is the intersection of all Sobolev spaces. On a compact manifold it is $C^\infty$. In any case it is a Frechet space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lie algebra of vector fields of a smooth manifold determines the manifold with its smooth structure. Below I indicate a series of papers where this is proved in various settings. In particular, this implies that any Lie algebra involution of the Lie algebra of vector fields has to be induced by an involution of the manifold.

- MR0064764 (16,331a) 
  Shanks, M. E.; Pursell, Lyle E.
  The Lie algebra of a smooth manifold. 
  Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 5, (1954). 468–472.
- MR0375400 (51 #11594)
  Amemiya, Ichiro; Masuda, Kazuo; Shiga, Kōji
  Lie algebras of differential operators. 
  Osaka J. Math. 12 (1975), 139–172.
- MR0516602 (80g:57036)
  Grabowski, J.
  Isomorphisms and ideals of the Lie algebras of vector fields. 
  Invent. Math. 50 (1978/79), no. 1, 13–33.
- MR2785498 (2012b:58028) 
  Grabowski, Janusz(PL-PAN); Kotov, Alexei(LUX-CUL); Poncin, Norbert(LUX-CUL)
  Geometric structures encoded in the Lie structure of an Atiyah algebroid. (English summary) 
  Transform. Groups 16 (2011), no. 1, 137–160

Answer (score 2):

Extending Ian's comment, any involution on $M$ induces an involution on the Lie algebra of the vector fields on $M.$ There should be plenty of those.