# A special Lie subalgebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, smooth-manifolds, c-star-algebras

Motivated by comments of the following post [A question on involutions on the Lie algebra of vector fields](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176592/a-question-on-involutions-on-the-lie-algebra-of-vector-fields) we ask the following question:

Let $L$ be  a  Lie algebra. We consider the  Lie  subalgebra $$F_{L}=\{x\in L \mid ad(x) \text{is  a  finite rank operator on L}\}$$

Note that $L\to F_{L}$ is  a  functor on the category of Lie  algebras.

> 1.In what reference, I can find  some materials  about this  special Lie  subalgebra and the properties of this  functor(And the functor $A\to F_{A}$ in the thirth question below?
>
> 2.For  a  manifold $M$, what is $F_{L}$ where $L=\chi^{\infty}(M)$. Is it  always the zero Lie  algebra? That is:is there  a  manifold  for  which $F_{L}$ is  a nontrivial Lie  algebra?
>
> 3.A $C^{*}$ algebra  $A$,is a Lie algebra $A$ in  an obvious manner. So $F_{A}$ is  a pre $C^{*}$ algebra. We denote its completion by $F_{A}$ again.  Is it true to say that $F_{M_{}n}(A)\sim M_{n}(F_{A})$?
>
> Moreover  what is $F_{A}$ for for $A=B(H)$?

Comment: I presume $add(x)$ means $ad(x)$?

Comment: @AllenKnutson Thanks for your correction I revise it.